# IntelliJ cannot resolve androidx AOSP

Tags: intellij-idea, android-source, androidx

I am working on an AOSP project and I am trying to setup IntelliJ.

I have added in the .bp file of my project this line :

```
static_libs :[
  ...
  androidx.appcompat_appcompat
  ...
]
```

The projects builds, but IntelliJ cannot resolve the dependency, and does not find android.appcompat even though `mm` compiled properly with my Activity extending AppCompatActivity.

I have setup the project with idegen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the best way to get aosp connected with an IDE is using AIDEGEN. I have never been able to get idegen working properly. Try aidegen. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/asuite/+/refs/heads/master/aidegen/README.md

Comment: Hello Rajat. Sorry I forgot to answer. This worked really well, thank you.